# dividing two expected values

Tags: probability, expected-value

Is the result of dividing two expected values, a new expected value?
In fact, in the probability theory, if $\mathbb{E}_1$ and $\mathbb{E}_2$ are two expected values, then is $\frac{\mathbb{E}_1}{\mathbb{E}_2}$ a new expected value?

I want to know, in general, is the expected value of the ratio of two random variables, the ratio of the expected values?

Comment: If $E_2\neq0$ then $E1/E2$ is a real number. For *every* real number $r$ we can define a random variable $X$ such that its expected value equals $r$. Just let $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ be described by $\omega\mapsto r$. Then $X$ is a random variable with $\mathbb EX=r$. For completeness: no, we do not have in general that $\mathbb E[X_1/X_2]=\mathbb EX_1/\mathbb EX_2$ (if that's what you mean).

Comment: In general, is the expected value of the ratio of two random variables, the ratio of the expected values?

Comment: As @drhab pointed out, no, in general $\mathbb E[\frac{X}{Y}] \neq \frac{\mathbb E[X]}{\mathbb E[Y]}$. Moreover it might happen that while $\mathbb E[ \frac{X}{Y}]$ is non-zero finite, you can have   $\mathbb E[Y]$ infinite or $0$, which could be a problem